# NSShadow and paper-curl effect in Desktop

Tags: cocoa, shadow, nsshadow

i was playing with some source code from this blog:
http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths

because i wanted to replicate its paper-curl effect with the shadow.
But it seems the property shadowPath of CALayer is not available in OSX, only in iPhone.

Could anyone suggest another method to achieve that kind of effect?

bets regards

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use CIPageCurlTransition?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I ended up using an NSBezierPath with shadow. I draw the bezier path with an offset for the shadow in the y-axis. After that, i draw the picture on top of it, in a position that hides the path but keeps the shadow visible. The effect is quite similar. I didn't notice that Transition. I will look into it. Thanks.